# How to set crowdsourcing platform in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crowdsourcing

I am new as `rails developer`. I have crowdsourcing platform code which is on [code for crowd sourcing platform](http://github.com/lockitron/selfstarter)

And want to put this on my rails application domain. From where I have to start and what I have to do for complete this task?

Thanks for reply in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crowdsourcing platform you mention - [Selfstarter](https://github.com/lockitron/selfstarter) - is a rails app itself.

Here's what you need to get started:

1. Pull the code down to your computer from the github repo with the following command:

   `git clone https://github.com/lockitron/selfstarter.git`
2. change directory into the cloned repo directory:

   `cd selfstarter`
3. Create the database and the tables with the following command:

   `bundle install --without production`
4. Start the rails server:

   `rails server`
5. Access the client from `the url http://localhost:3000`

You will have the bare bones selfstarter app as shown in the image below:
[image: SelfStarter Local app]

All this is explained in [the README of the selfstarter github repo](https://github.com/lockitron/selfstarter/blob/master/README.md).

To be able to understand how this was done, and to be able to customize the app for your specific needs, it would help if you learn the basics of Ruby on Rails. I would strongly recommend the freely available online [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial)

Comment: when i follow 3rd step it gives error : Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler 
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks! i also try command **bundle install** but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try changing the source in Gemfile as suggested here: https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1776#issuecomment-4558915 Might help....

Comment: Now i have to put this crowd sourcing platform in my domain. what i have to do?